# Magento cron not running properly.any other methods

Tags: magento2

For some strange reason my cron jobs are not running anymore the last in magento 2.3.4 cron jobs on the server are running well without any problems.But after some time cron not running.Can you help me to running without any delay.

Answer (score 0):

kindly check your db when its last time triggered using this query and check  your sytem log and exception log  to get what problem occurs which causes its stoppage:

```
SELECT * FROM cron_schedule ORDER BY  schedule_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

OR:

you can run the cron by command:

php bin/magento cron:run

Comment: sir i would like to run cron job without any delay continuously